# Improving mysql query performance on large table

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables with the size of:

A - 700M rows

B - 1M rows

C - 10K rows

The relationship between the tables is one to many:

Each row in C corresponds to multiple rows in B, each row in B corresponds to multiple rows in A.

I want to select (some fields of) records from table B and for each record get the average(records) from A.

with the query below it takes ~20 hours.

How can I improve this query?

```
SELECT B.info1, B.info2, AVG(A.data1)
FROM A
INNER JOIN B ON A.data2 = B.info3 AND A.data3 = B.info4
INNER JOIN C ON A.data2 = C.foo1
WHERE B.info5 = 'value'
AND B.info6 like 'value%' 
AND B.info7 = value
AND NOT C.foo2 = 'value'
group by A.data2, A.data3;
```

Comment: I would "inner join C on b.info3 = c.foo1" iso. "INNER JOIN C ON A.data2 = C.foo1".  How many rows from A will this query need to retrieve?  What indexes do you have on the three tables?  You have 'value' and value.  Typo or meaningful?

Comment: Table C isn't the issue here as I understand. the query retrieves about 30K rows. I have indexes on the columns which I use in the JOINs. when I use explain() I get 400K in rows for table A. 'value' is just a place holder, you can ignore it.

Comment: Please post the output of EXPLAIN EXTENDED: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html

Comment: Maybe MySQL has as much difficulties answering your queries as you have answering mine. But I bet after 20h you have a useful answer, which can't be said about yours.  What indexes do you have on the three tables?

Answer (score 0):

Index needed:

```
B:  (info5, info7, info6)
A:  (data2, data3, data1)
C:  (foo1, foo2)
```

If you run `EXPLAIN`, it will probably show that `B` is first.  Hence, my focus is on the columns needed for filtering in `B`.  I put the `=` columns first, then the "range".

After that, it may go into `C` and `A` where I provided "covering" indexes.

Another approach is, instead of `JOINing` to `A`, select

```
( SELECT AVG(data1) FROM A
      WHERE data2 = B.info3  AND data3 = B.info4
) AS 'Average'
```

Comment: `B.info3` and `B.info4` are also need indexes cause they used for `JOIN..ON`

Comment: @Kondybas - The optimizer is likely to start with `B`, so 5,7,6 are useful for the `WHERE`.  What is your point?

Comment: `ON A.data2 = B.info3` need both sides of comparison to be indexed.